# Set up a server to connect to existing queue and get values from it

Tags: python, concurrency, rabbitmq, celery

I'm learning celery. **I want to get values from existing queue and process them.** I search a lot and every time I reach **"inspect"**.

I do 2 things:

- inspect worker
- reply_to the certain server

maybe needs to use pika for that? i dont know -_-
UPDATE
im using pika to retrive tasks from the queue but when used reply_to attribite the status of task remains PENDING and pended tasks go to queue and pended tasks are getted. why celery frameWork is so confusing!!!

```py
from celery import Celery,signals
import time 
import numpy as np
from celery.signals import after_task_publish
# =====================================================================
app = Celery('gen_num', broker='amqp://guest:guest@-',backend='rpc://')
app.config_from_object('config')
# =====================================================================
@app.task
def gen_num(num):
# time.sleep(1)
    A = np.random.default_rng(seed=num)
    a = A.integers(low=0, high=100)
    message = (a,a+1)
    return message

---- UPDATE ----


# =====================================================================
# ................................................................
# ............................PIKA................................
# ........................pika....................................
import pika
import ast
import time
import numpy as np
import json
# —————————————————
# Connection section
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('***','***')

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('ip',
                                   port,
                                   'vhost',
                                   credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()  #print(help(channel))

# get data from queue
a = channel.basic_get(queue='--*--', auto_ack=True)
# ................................................................
# ............................PIKA................................
# ........................pika....................................
# ............................PIKA................................
# ................................................................
```

Comment: i am using pika for send tasks but another problem has been raised. when use reply_to attribute the task always been PENDING. when not use it it turn into SUCCESS

Comment: Are you using `celery` in both client and the worker?

Comment: hi @LemonReddy. i dont understand whats you mean. i have a queue and want to get values from it. with pika i can do that but reply_to is made tasks PENDING

Comment: Instead of using pika to add messages to the queue. You can use celery to add messages. pika is a python interface to RabbitMQ and celery builds on top of RabbitMQ. It abstracts over RabbitMQ concepts and creates exchange, routing_key and body internally and deals at task level. First, deciding whether celery fits your use case and if it does, remove pika altogether unless you want to provide channel, routing_key and body by yourself(useful when you have services in multiple programming languages).

Comment: @LemonReddy thanks for sharing your answer. i use pika to get the message from a queue not send message. for sending i use celery. can celery connect to a preconstrate queue and get message from it?  i want this: create server 1 and generate number from it and server 1 send result to the specific queue and server 2 connect to this queue and get the values, process them and send them to new specifiv que. finally server 1 connect to this que and get values of it.  Now i create server 1 and generate number but send pending task to my que. and when get them there is a tuple of odd report of them

Comment: I have never used pika. But from a quick glance, it looks like a python wrapper for RabbitMQ. Celery is a distributed task queue. The whole purpose of it is to be scalable and execute tasks on a different process(on a different machine) while using broker for Inter Process Communication. Single Celery process can be both used to send and receive tasks. Remove pika and configure celery correctly and it will work as expected for your use case. At the end of task execution in server2, add task to the queue on which server1 is listening on.